# Limit the amount of times a shell script can be executed

Tags: bash, shell

How can i limit the amount of times a shell script can be executed.  I have tried shc but that only has time limits and not usage limits.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to prevent the script from being called in parallel, or do you want the script to refuse to run when running for the n-th or more time?

Comment: Yes, say for example the script has been ran 3 times, on the 4th time i would like it to not run and just show a message like Please contact xxx@sss.com

Comment: And what should happen if the user makes copies of the script and runs them instead?

Comment: Most likely, it's not the number of times the script runs that you want to limit, it's the number of times it accesses some resource. Instead of allowing the script to access the resource directly, force it to go through a separate API that can independently verify the source of the request and enforce any limits itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a file as the "run counter" and read that file during execution to see how many times the script has been previously run.

If you want the "numOfRuns.txt" file to persist after reboots, use a different directory than /tmp as the root.

Here is a `limitedScript.sh` that demonstrates this, first without comments, then with.

```
#!/bin/bash

runCountFile="/tmp/numOfRuns.txt"
maxRuns=3

if [ -e "$runCountFile" ]; then
    read value < "$runCountFile"
else
    value=0
fi

if ((value >= maxRuns)); then
    echo "Script has been run too many times"
    exit
else
    newValue=$((value + 1))
    echo $newValue > "$runCountFile"
fi
```

--

```
#!/bin/bash

# limitedScript.sh: Demonstrates simple run-limiting through a file-based counter

runCountFile="/tmp/numOfRuns.txt" # the file to store the number of times the script has run
maxRuns=3 # maximum number of executions for this script

if [ -e "$runCountFile" ]; then # does the run counter file exist?
    value=`cat $runCountFile` # read the value from the file
else
    value=0 # the script has never run yet if the "run counter" file doesn't exist
fi

if ((value >= maxRuns)); then
    echo "Script has been run too many times"
    exit
else
    newValue=$((value + 1))
    echo $newValue > "$runCountFile" #update the "run counter" file
fi
```

OUTPUT:

```
root@dev:/tmp# rm numOfRuns.txt
root@dev:/tmp# ./limitedScript.sh
root@dev:/tmp# ./limitedScript.sh
root@dev:/tmp# ./limitedScript.sh
root@dev:/tmp# ./limitedScript.sh
Script has been run too many times
```

Comment: `read value < "$runCountFile"` would suffice, without having to run an external program.

Comment: is there anyway to do this remotely so they can't use the script on more than the set amount of servers, or is that impossible

Comment: You would need the script to validate with a remote counter in one of your servers. This does not prevent the "customer" to copy the script and edit the validation out to run the script as much as he likes.
You could write the script in python instead and compile it with the py_compile module, then from the python cli: '>>>import py_compile   >>> py_compile.compile('myscript.py')'